# How to reshape my data for linear regression?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am trying to perform a linear regression for my data. But I have a reshaping problem for my data. I got this error:

```
array=[1547977519 1547977513].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X=[1547977519, 1547977513]
Y=[1, 1]

#X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
print(X)
#Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)
print(Y)
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, X)
print(reg.score(X, Y))
```

I try to add .reshape but it does not work correctly. It gives me this error:

```
    X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Comment: reshape function only applies to array https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html . Convert your list to array and then use numpy.reshape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `numpy.array` which has the method `reshape`

```
from numpy import array
>>> x = array([1547977519, 1547977513])
>>> x.reshape(-1,1)
array([[1547977519],
       [1547977513]])
```